# Joining 2 sql tables based on substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I am trying to join tables where the only 2 keys which match are `table1.Account` and `table2.key`

But the problem is the setup. The `table1.Account` field has 10 digits and only the middle 4 or 5 digits match with the table2.key

```
eg : 1234xxxx10 - > table1.Account matches with xxxx -> table2.key

or   123xxxxx10 - > table1.Account matches with xxxxx -> table2.key
```

I've written this piece of INNER JOIN code but the query keeps on running and is not giving me back anything.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2
from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.Account like '%'+table2.key+'%'
order by column1
```

Comment: If you remove the `distinct` you should get some results faster.  And, how do you know if the middle 4 or 5 match?

Comment: maybe using left() would be faster than like

Comment: So you have to deal with a very bad database design. Your best bet would be to change it so that separate information is in separate columns. If you must solve this with a query alone, however, you must first declare the rule by which you find the substring in question. Is it always the four or five characters before the last two in the string? What if both one record matches four characters and another five? Constitute that rule and only then think about how to write the query.

Answer (score 3):

SQL has a substring function:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2
from table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
    ON table1.Account = substring(table2.key, 3, 4)
    OR table1.Account = substring(table2.key, 4, 4)
order by column1
```

I don't know if you need the 'or' in your on clause, but based on your question it seems like there may be two ways for those fields to match up.  Regardless, you can modify the on clause, as needed, but this sample should help you with the syntax, which appears to be your obstacle.

Comment: I cannot imagine how the performance for this would be any different from the performance of the original query.

Comment: Well since he is using like and wildcards to compare a 4 or 5 character field with a 10 character field, he needs to make 7 comparisons for each attempted join, whereas mine makes only 1 or 2, depending on whether or not he needs the second part of the on clause.

Comment: For example with table1.Account = 'ABCDEFGHIJ' and table2.Key = 'DEFG', substring(table1.Account, 4, 4) = table2.key makes 1 comparison, whereas table2.key like '%' + table1.ACcount + '%' can make 7 comparisons.

Comment: (1) `LIKE` is built-in so it is pretty efficient; (2) `substring()` might be faster; (3) That is irrelevant, because that is not why the query is slow.  Nested loop joins followed by `distinct` explain why it is slow, not string comparisons.

Comment: distinct obviously makes the query slower, but if that's what he needs, I don't know of another way to get the distinct values, short of returning everything and having an application loop through the results, which I would argue is bad design.  That said, what do you mean by nested loop joins, how do they apply here, and with what logic would you replace them?